# How do I autoload an external gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I recently externalized my rails models outside of my rails-app into a gem (models_gem).

When my rails project imports the models_gem, i have to do a: require 'model' , in order to use the model.  How can I automatically import all the models that are in my models_gem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require a gem, it requires lib/gem_name.rb. If you require all the models in that file, in theory they should be loaded in your application.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in Gemfile eg:

```
gem 'models_gem', require: 'models_gem'
```

or fix your gem and in lib/models_gem.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ModelsGem)
```

Thats depends how your gem is made.

Comment: By default Bundler automatically requires gems so doing require: 'models_gem' is redundant.